# How do I get this SQL Server ODBC Connection working?

Tags: sql-server, odbc

Note: I've obviously changed the server names and IPs to fictitious ones.

Here's what's going on. I've got a server, which I'm calling `MYSERVER`, running Microsoft SQL Server Express 2005. Right on this server itself, I've got an ODBC connection set up pointing at itself, and that already works perfectly. I log in using SQL Server Authentication (not Windows authentication), and it's set up like this:

[image: Image of good ODBC connection]

Like I said, that one works. But next, I've got another computer which is on a totally different domain/not on the intranet, that needs to access this same SQL Server hosted on MYSERVER. Because it's on a different domain, it doesn't recognize the name "MYSERVER"; I have to point it at the IP address of MYSERVER, which we'll say is 123.456.789.012. But the ODBC connection doesn't seem to work there. I tried setting it up like this:

[image: Image of bad ODBC connection]

This doesn't work. When I put in the username and password and press Next, it stalls for a good 10 to 20 seconds, and then finally comes back with the following error:

```
Connection failed:
SQLState: '01000'
SQL Server Error: 1326
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()).
Connection failed:
SQLState: '08001'
SQL Server Error: 17
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
```

If I try the same thing, but change the "server" from `123.456.789.012\SQLEXPRESS` to just plain old `123.456.789.012`, I get a different error:

```
Connection failed:
SQLState: '01000'
SQL Server Error: 14
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Invalid Instance()).
Connection failed:
SQLState: '08001'
SQL Server Error: 14
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]Invalid connection.
```

Now I know what you're thinking. You might be thinking, "duh, you probably didn't open the firewall for port 1433, dummy." Except I did, and I verified this, as I can **successfully** run:

```
telnet 123.456.789.012 1433
```

...from the command line all I want. So I'm not sure what to do. I know the SQL Server exists, works, and an ODBC connection *can* be set up properly; I'm just not sure what it is I've got wrong in my connection settings that's throwing these errors. Based on the latter error I listed, it would seem that it can connect to the server, but simply cannot find the instance (since I didn't specify one that time). So does that mean I just need to use some different syntax to specify the IP along with an instance name? What do I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Named pipes and TCIP protocols for SQL server 2005 are disabled by default. Have you enabled them under "SQL server configuration manager"? You can find the protocols in the SQL Server Network configuration and under SQL Native client xx configuration.

The connection on the server itself works thanks to the "Shared memory" protocol.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because it got me on the right track. Under SQL Server Configuration Manager, TCP/IP was already enabled all along under "SQL Server 2005 Network Configuration > Protocols for SQLEXPRESS" and "SQL Native Client Configuration > Client Protocols." Named Pipes was already enabled in the latter. I enabled it in the former, but that didn't seem to help (same error messages). Finally, I switched the ODBC source to use the "SQL Native Client" driver instead of the "SQL Server" driver, and that finally DID work.

Comment: Thank you SoaperGEM!  I never would have thought to have tried SQL Native Client!  Worked like a charm!

Comment: How did u switched the ODBC source to use the "SQL Native Client" driver ?

Answer (score 6):

Have you enabled the *SQL Server Browser service* as per [How to configure SQL Server 2005 to allow remote connections](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;914277)?:

> If you are running SQL Server 2005 by
>   using an instance name and you are not
>   using a specific TCP/IP port number in
>   your connection string, you must
>   enable the SQL Server Browser service
>   to allow for remote connections. For
>   example, SQL Server 2005 Express is
>   installed with a default instance name
>   of Computer Name\SQLEXPRESS.

Comment: Does connecting to the server\instance on the local use a different mechanism than remotely??

Comment: @Sam see Hakan Winther answer.

Answer (score 5):

[This thread](http://dbaspot.com/forums/sqlserver-server/251219-error-connecting-remote-server.html) fixed the same error message for me when using Access to connect to a MSSQL 2008 server. MSSQL 2005 and earlier worked fine just using the computer name in the connection string, but I had to change to the connection string in Access to the full form when the instance was upgraded to 2008:

`servername\instancename,portnumber`

Comment: That did it for me, except I didn't need the port number.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and managed to resolve it by changing the SQL driver to the SQL Native Client driver too. This was weird as in my case this had been working fine for years and then just stopped working. I suspect this is something along the lines of the driver being corrupt, perhaps a reinstal of MDAC might assist, but for the time being I'm happy that it is working at all!

Answer (score 1):

Would it recognize the server name if it were fully qualified?  If it were MYSERVER.domain.com?  We've had to do that with SQL Server when connecting from a different domain.  If you can get the ODBC System DSN to connect when you test the data source, you're making progress.  If it doesn't connect in the ODBC setup, you have to fix that first.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do--to get the ODBC System DSN to connect in the first place when I test the data source. So I tried your suggestion, trying both `MYSERVER.domain.com\SQLEXPRESS` and `MYSERVER.domain.com`, but those both gave me the same errors I listed above, respectively.

Comment: At a command prompt on the other computer type  "nslookup MYSERVER.domain.com" - does that resolve to the right IP address (123.456.789.012) or at all?

Comment: @Sim - Yes, that command *does* resolve properly.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using named pipes or TCP on the ODBC connection that does work? Is TCP enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have remote tcp connectios enabled for the SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild shot here but what happens if you put a double backslash before the server name or IP address? It just seems to me that it's normally required for most other Windows/Microsoft connections.

Comment: Trying the double backslash results in the same 1326 error (the first one I listed).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In my case another sw configures the ODBC setting so i cannot change the driver. I solved my case like this:

1. Set TCP/IP settings for server to use the port 1433
2. On the client enter the server address like: 192.168.1.5,1433 (no instance name)

Then it started to work.
Client OS: Win7 x64
Driver: sqlsrv32.dll

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I started getting this error on a connection that had been previously working.  It turned out that the MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS service had somehow got stopped. Restarting it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, and it was as simple as this: the server listed as the primary DNS server for this server was removed, and the app was no longer able to correctly resolve the SQL server's name on the network. Everything immediately started working again when I corrected the local DNS server to a functioning one.